# Sending a push notification to android device using amazon sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

i already follow the instruction given http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html#registration-id-gcm. But my created app didnt received any notification.

Can someone shed light on me.

Comment: Maybe provide some example code that you've tried and the particular stuff you think that doesn't work?  Otherwise, not sure we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, i created a new project in android studio an import the snssamples folder and supply the necessary variables.

Comment: String registrationId = "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String serverAPIKey = "AIXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String applicationName = “AppName";
snsClientWrapper.demoNotification(Platform.GCM, "", serverAPIKey,
        registrationId, applicationName, attributesMap);

Answer (score -1):

You have:

- Installed the Android SDK
- Installed the Google Play Services SDK
- Installed the Android Support Library package
- Registered your app with GCM to receive push notification message
  (you have a registration ID)

If not, start at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html.